# Via usages and rules

Tags: prepositions, terminology, word-usage

Is the use of via below correct ?

"Read about ... via [website title]."

I had thought via is when u got something through/from/by means or ways of... I can simply substitute the above with on, but would like to know if via is used correctly here.

It sounds ok when it is "posted at 1129hr via Twitter", but am not to sure about "read about ... via [website title]"

Comment: IMHO, you read about [something] **at** or **on** a website, not *through* a website - which is what *via* means.

Answer (score -1):

It's fine. Wiktionary, in its definition of [via](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/via#Preposition) as a preposition, uses:

> By (means of); using (a medium)

which allows conceptual devices (mediums, or media) to be appropriated to 'via'.

This differs from the original etymology of 'via', which uses a more physical sense (I wish to travel from A to B via C), but has become common usage nonetheless.

Comment: I don't think you can read the news *via* a newspaper (unless you're reading them through a hole in it).

Comment: This shows a common misconception. The Wiktionary definition shows that 'by', 'by means of' etc are synonyms. This does not mean that the terms are always interchangeable. 'The blocks are raised by means of pulleys.' cannot be rendered  'The blocks are raised via pulleys.'